# How to correctly handle laravel queue jobs that didn't finish or fail

Tags: laravel, error-handling, queue, laravel-8, jobs

Suppose at some point the long running job (which is currently running) became irrelevant, i. e. other jobs with more relevant context had been generated. Now I don't need some running jobs (and other jobs that would be potentially generated by those).

Is there a correct way to stop running this job?

Comment: There should not be "a long running job". If you add more specific info about your job(s) we can help, else this is an opinion-based topic.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I mean the jobs that are not relevant anymore (like some analytics where the data became irrelevant). They could still be processed but their output is not needed.

Comment: And what is the information to know that the data inside the job is now irrelevant ? How do you know when it gets irrelevant ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti when new jobs of certain types (related to the same model as running jobs that I'm looking to stop) are created and dispatched. i. e. I'm running some analytics on certain input and that input changes, while previous analytics jobs are still running.

Comment: I am not sure how could you achieve this, one would be to ask the DB if it should do it, or a cache. But there is no clear answer.